# Passing an array from Angular to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have a dropdown form where you can select one or more items. The selected items I want to send to a backend php script that will insert the selected values  into a database. 
This is my angular insert function:

```
insertRepair: function (id_telefon, id_culoare, arrayPiese) {
                console.log(arrayPiese);
                http.get('../php/insert_reparatii.php', {
                    params: {id_telefon: id_telefon, arrayPiese: arrayPiese,
                        id_culoare: id_culoare}
                }).then(function () {
                }
            }
```

The call to this function is done like this:

```
serviceHttp.insertRepair($scope.phoneMP.selected.id, $scope.colorMP.selected.id, $scope.selectedPiesaMP.selected);
```

If I print into the console the `arrayPiese` array it will print for 2 selected items, something like this:

```
["Adezivi_Rama", "Polarizator"]
```

Now in the backend I retrieve the array list:

```
$arr = $_REQUEST['arrayPiese'];
```

If I print the $arr variable I get only one of two items printed.
Need to mention that I migrated from jquery to angular, and from jquery I was able to send the entire array like this:

```
var arrayPiese = [];
$('.select2-selection__choice').each(function () {
    arrayPiese.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The url looks like this `arrayPiese=Adezivi_Rama&arrayPiese=Polarizator&id_culoare=1&id_telefon=18`

Do I need to serialize the array before sending it to php? Or what would be the best approach in sending an array to backend??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayPiese=Adezivi_Rama&arrayPiese=Polarizator` will result in a single variable `$_REQUEST['arrayPiese']` with the value `Polarizator` because the latter overwrites the first one.

If you want to pass an array, you have to append brackets to the query parameter name:

```
arrayPiese[]=Adezivi_Rama&arrayPiese[]=Polarizator
```

…which will result in a PHP variable `$_REQUEST['arrayPiese']` with an array value like:

```
[
    0 => 'Adezivi_Rama',
    1 => 'Polarizator'
]
```

Comment: hmm, looks easy, need to see how to append the brackets in angular

Comment: @AndreiMaieras I bet there is a method in Angular for this use case…

Comment: I found a solution by changing array param in the `params`object like this: `"arrayPiese[]":arrayPiese` so for me this would be the accepted response

Answer (score 4):

You can pass array as json,

```
http.get('../php/insert_reparatii.php', {params: {id_telefon: id_telefon, arrayPiese:angular.toJson(arrayPiese),
            id_culoare: id_culoare}
    }).then(function () {
    }
```

Then in your PHP script, convert json to PHP array,

```
    $arrayPiese = json_decode($_GET['arrayPiese'], TRUE);
```